# .desktop file not executing

Tags: desktop-file

I just recently downloaded a game called Starsector and instead of going into the folder every time and running `./starsector.sh`, I want to create a desktop entry. Below is my current `.desktop` file called `starsector.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Starsector
GenericName=Starsector
Exec=sh -c "cd /usr/games/starsector && sudo ./starsector.sh"
Terminal=false
Icon=/usr/games/starsector/graphics/icons/cargo/ai_core_alpha.png
Type=Application
Categories=Game
```

I have moved this file into `~/.local/share/applications`. When copying the `Exec` line and running it in my shell, it runs the game perfectly fine, but when clicking on the icon it does nothing.

###### Things I have tried

I have tried to set Terminal=true 
Run `desktop-file-validate`; there are no errors present 
Adding exec permissions to the file
Copying file to the desktop and clicking "Allow launching"
Running `gio set myapp.desktop metadata::trusted yes`

As of now, the file permissions are `-rw-rw-r--`. I don't know if this is a file permission problem or simply a problem with the game executable itself somehow.

EDIT:

###### More things I have tried

Setting `Exect=sh -c "cd /usr/game/starsector && sh ./starsector.sh` 
Changed owner and group of `starsector.sh` from `root` to my own user
Changed owner and group of `starsector.desktop` from my own user to `root:root`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you don't need `sudo` permission to execute it. Try changing your `Exec` line to `Exec=sh "/usr/games/startsector/starsector.sh"` ...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. When running that command from the command line, I get an error saying `./jre_linux/bin/java: not found`. I've noticed that this only seems to happen when I try to directly run the `.sh` file. It looks like I first need to `cd` into the directory or it yells at me.

Comment: I see, it's a `java` application... Does it work if you change it to `Exec=sh -c "cd /usr/games/starsector && sh starsector.sh`? This way it should work without having execution permission... When you execute it with `./starsector.sh` you need at least `-rwxrw-r--` permissions (which could be done with `chmod +x /path/starsector.sh`)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. See my post again, I added more things I have tried. I kept wondering if it was a permissions problem, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was extremely simple. All I had to do was add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the `.desktop` file and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: At the top of the _`.desktop` file_? Why? It's not a `bash` script.

Comment: Honestly, I'm trying to figure this out myself. When the actual game is run, I am running `starsector.sh` which _is_ a `bash` script. The only thing I can guess is that I needed to let it know that I'm going to be executing a shell script with the `Exec` line. It's very weird, but it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

change mode to execute startsector.sh

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/games/starsector/starsector.sh
```

change mode to execute startsector.desktop

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/starsector.desktop
```

change EXEC inside desktop file

```bsh
Exec=/usr/games/starsector/starsector.sh
```

Comment: Why would the `.desktop` file need to be executable? (And why move it from the user's home directory?) The shell script appears to already be executable, or otherwise `sudo ./starsector.sh` would not work.